# HTML Input Fields Styling

Tags: html, input

How do I modify the style of the text the user is inputting in a `<input type='text' placeholder='Text here'></input>` field. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to style them...just like any other element, but browsers have their own styling in place when it comes to form elements. You should reset this, then apply your styling. But even then, you might run into discrepancies among browsers. I would recommend finding a form reset in which someone has already worked out the nuances when it comes to styling forms.

By the way, input tags are self closing so it would look like this...

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Text here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do like this-

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Text here" style=""/>
```

In that style= "", you can apply any style related tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Use this CSS Code to change the color of the the text in the place holder.

input-placeholder {color:#909; }